# Boost mutex usage for multipart processes

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost

I have a c++ program with a socket communications class. Each socket has a large dedicated 
buffer for assembling an output message, so usage would be like:

```
class CSocketClass {
public:
    SetMsgHeader(int n) { Mutex_.lock(); DoWhateverIsNeededToSetHeaderInBuffer(n); } // where n would be the message type
    SetMsgField(double a); { DoWhateverIsNeededToSetDataInBuffer(a); } // where a would be some arbitrary content
    SendMsg(); { DoWhateverIsNeededToSendBuffer(); Mutex_.unlock(); } // where this would send the number of bytes added to the buffer since the   header was set
private:
    char buffer[reallylarge];
    MiscSocketApparatus... 
    boost::mutex   Mutex_;  
};
```

Multiple threads could be trying to send messages, each consisting of three or more calls the set the header, the content, and finally sending the message on its way. To keep them from conflicting, I've tried to keep only a single writer at a time by using the Mutex. The desired behavior would be for a second-to-arrive writer to be blocked until the first-to-arrive writer unlocked the mutex. Then the blocked writer would be able to proceed.

This seems to work most of the time, but on rare occasions (not every day), deadlocks still seem to occur.

I'm much more familiar with simpler lock issues using scoped locks, but those concepts may not translate perfectly to this problem, where the lock needs to be persistent across a number of calls to the object owning the lock.

From reading the Boost synchronication tutorial, I think there are better ways to do this, but its not clear what would be best.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since each thread has its own buffer, have each build the *complete* message in its own buffer, *then* lock the mutex and send the message.

Better still, have one thread to actually dispatch messages, and N threads to create them. Put a thread-safe queue in between, so a thread creates a message, puts it in the queue, then (if needed) goes back to creating another message. The message sender just constantly waits for a message in the queue, retrieves it, sends it, and repeats.

You probably also want a thread-safe collection of buffers, so when a message has been sent, the sending thread can put the buffer where a message-builder thread can use it again when needed.

As an aside: for the buffer I'd use an `std::string` or a `std::vector`, instead of a raw array.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up creating a private buffer message class, then using a scoped lock to copy the buffer to the common socket buffer and release the lock. The socket will send on its own schedule. As an aside, the std::string is incompatible with binary data (I'm sending blobs), and both use heap allocations, which are much slower than a private stack-based buffer, which has no allocation overhead.

Comment: @user2748924: std::string is fine with binary data (though that's the sort of thing I had in mind when suggesting `std::vector`). The speed is why I suggested a collection of buffers, so you'd allocate buffers up-front, then re-use them, so you only have to allocate each once.